# How to log all the queries in a log file in a java application with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, logging, morphia

I have a java application which use [morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) to work with mongodb.

I want to log all the queries sent to mongodb in a file, which I can analyze them to improve the performance. But I don't find a way to log them.

I know mongodb can log the queries in `system.profile` collection, but I still want a log file.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use SLF4J or Logback/Log4J? Add Morphias' [SLF4JExtension](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/SLF4JExtension) to your CLASSPATH.

Then simply enable `com.google.code.morphia` logger and log it wherever you want.

Comment: I am trying to print the JSON query, added SL4JExtension, and enabled log by in my log4j.properties as log4j.logger.com.google.code.morphia= DEBUG but it only show mapping log, 2012-06-14 10:55:21,450 DEBUG [com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedClass] - MappedClass done: MappedClass....... I want to print the query. Please can you guide

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Morphia (version 1.3.2) on top of Java MongoDB driver (version 3.9.1), and I was able to enable the actual query logging (using Log4j2) by setting `org.mongodb.morphia` logger level to `trace`. That is, in my `log4j2.xml`:

```
<Loggers>
    ...
    <Logger name="org.mongodb.morphia" level="trace" />
    ...
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Wildfly` deployment, I managed to enable Morphia logging by adding the following to the `stadalone.xml`:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:15.0">
  <profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
      <logger category="org.mongodb.morphia" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
          <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
      </logger>
    </subsystem>
  </profile>
</server>
```